# Remove Flag Status on two Folders

Tags: vba, outlook

With the following Code I set Flag Status "Complete" to one defined Folder (ID) on Outlook Startup. Is it possible to define a second Folder with another ID and separated Filter for e.g. "<= 1" and with the Flagstatus "olNoFlag"?

I tried to duplicate the whole Code, rename the Function name and set another Foldername, but without success.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim Item As Object
    Flagge_setzen Item
End Sub

Private Function Flagge_setzen(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Set olShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("test@test.com")

    Dim olShareInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Set olShareInbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)

    Dim Completed_Fldrs As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Completed_Fldrs = olNs.GetFolderFromID("0000000008F2D77ECE07A24EB6C27E0843C4B8880100CE3F23E508AB4F4A9A91BD99E6604421000000004C380000")

    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & _
                 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" & _
                           Chr(34) & ">1"

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Completed_Fldrs.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    Dim Mail As MailItem

    Dim i As Long
    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set Mail = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Mail.Subject
            Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
            Mail.Save
        End If
    Next

End Function


Sub GetFoldersEntryID()
    Dim olfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olfolder = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
    Debug.Print olfolder.EntryID
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
There's a few things that could be improved in the code (why are you using a function that returns nothing, and takes an object that it doesn't use? and hardcoded IDs aren't the best thing but I guess they work).

After you set the first folder (the items in the first folder technically) you can repeat the process for a different filter+folder, so, something like:

```
Private Function Flagge_setzen(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Set olShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("test@test.com")

    Dim olShareInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Set olShareInbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)

    Dim Completed_Fldrs As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Completed_Fldrs = olNs.GetFolderFromID("0000000008F2D77ECE07A24EB6C27E0843C4B8880100CE3F23E508AB4F4A9A91BD99E6604421000000004C380000")

    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & _
                 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" & _
                           Chr(34) & ">1"

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Completed_Fldrs.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    Dim Mail As MailItem

    Dim i As Long
    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set Mail = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Mail.Subject
            Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
            Mail.Save
        End If
    Next
'Now you repeat for another folder
    Set Completed_Fldrs = olNs.GetFolderFromID("TheNewID")
    Filter = "The new filter"
    Set Items = Completed_Fldrs.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set Mail = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Mail.Subject
            Mail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
            Mail.Save
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the code works. The Problem was that the flags where removed in OWA, but not in the Outlook program. I think it takes a little bit to synchronize. Can you tell me, how i can improve the Code? The Code was from another user in this forum (thanks to 0m3r)

Comment: No answer anymore?